# Oracle Apex 5.1: Edit link in report not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have made an interactive report with a From. My report is made by joining two database tables. After creating the report and the form page I changed my Form Type from "Normal" to "Modal Dialogue" in page designer and also made several changes in the form page.

When I run the report page and click the "Edit" link in the report the form page appears but the form field is not fetching any data to be updated. Also there is no "Delete" button and "Save" button in the from which are supposed to be there.

Could anyone help me correct the edit link so that when I click the edit link I can edit data and save or delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the report page and click the "Edit" link in the report the form page appears but the form field is not fetching any data to be updated.

What are the values in session? Did you check those ? After changing Normal page to Modal page make sure you are passing ITEM and Value to you're modal page when user clicks on EDIT link.

> Also there is no "Delete" button and "Save" button in the from which are supposed to be there.

This button must be conditional. Lets say for an example i wanted to see Delete and Save button when One of my page item have some value(where by i can make sure i'm editing something in this case) if not then i am creating new stuff so i don't need to see Delete and Save button.